# Rendering Plaintext as HTML maintaining whitespace – without <pre>

Tags: javascript, python, html, algorithm, plaintext

Given any arbitrary text file full of printable characters, how can this be converted to HTML that would be rendered exactly the same (with the following requirements)?

- Does not rely on any but the default HTML whitespace rules

  - No `<pre>` tag
  - No CSS `white-space` rules
- `<p>` tags are fine, but not required (`<br />`s and/or `<div>`s are fine)
- Whitespace is maintained exactly.

  Given the following lines of input (ignore erroneous auto syntax highlighting):

  ```
  Line one
      Line two, indented    four spaces
  ```

  A browser should render the output exactly the same, maintaining the indentation of the second line and the gap between "indented" and "spaces". Of course, I am not actually looking for monospaced output, and the font is orthogonal to the algorithm/markup.

  Given the two lines as a complete input file, example correct output would be:

  ```
  Line one<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Line two, 
  indented&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; four spaces
  ```
- Soft wrapping in the browser is desirable. That is, the resulting HTML should not force the user to scroll, even when input lines are wider than their viewport (assuming individual words are still narrowing than said viewport).

I’m looking for fully defined **algorithm.** Bonus points for implementation in **python** or **javascript**.

*(Please do not just answer that I should be using `<pre>` tags or a CSS `white-space` rule, as my requirements render those options untenable. Please also don’t post untested and/or naïve suggestions such as “replace all spaces with `&nbsp;`.” After all, I’m positive a solution is technically possible — it’s an interesting problem, don’t you think?)*

Comment: What's wrong with "replace all spaces with &nbsp;"? Just asking, it's the first thing that came to mind - of course you'd also need to replace line breaks with `<br>` and expand tabs somehow.

Comment: "it's an interesting problem, don't you think?" - not really. It's a problem that's already solved for you in more than one way.

Comment: @delnan, probably because this won't allow to browser to wrap long lines

Comment: Are you only concerned with whitespace at the beginning of the line, or do you want to preserve the positioning of text within the line?  Or, in other words, are there columns in your text that you want to preserve?

Comment: I'm extremely curious what possible set of constraints could prohibit all the obvious and legitimate solutions that exist.

Comment: @gilly3 Anywhere in the line, white space should be preserved — with the exception that the browser should be able to soft-wrap text, to be precise.

Comment: @nick For example, if you are using `contentEditable`, some browsers (Firefox) completely choke when the content has any but the default `white-space` interpretation.

Comment: @Alan Then why not just use <pre> tags?

Comment: @nick Because text in `<pre>` tags doesn't soft-wrap, and they would probably have the same issue in Firefox under `contentEditable` mode.

Comment: @matt I’m having a hard time not reading your comment as unnecessarily douche-y and presumptuous.

Comment: @Alan H. - your problem itself is unnecessary (and boring, imo). Stating my opinion isn't douche-y. Don't take things so personally.

Comment: @matt “Your problem is unnecessary.” You don’t know that. The naïve solutions I mention above are untenable due to constraints alluded to above. If the solution is so obvious, please answer!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution to do that while still allowing the browser to **wrap long lines** is to replace each sequence of two spaces with a space and a non break space.

The browser will correctly render all spaces (normal and non break ones), while still wrapping long lines (due to normal spaces).

Javascript:

```
text = html_escape(text); // dummy function
text = text.replace(/\t/g, '    ')
           .replace(/  /g, '&nbsp; ')
           .replace(/  /g, ' &nbsp;') // second pass
                                      // handles odd number of spaces, where we 
                                      // end up with "&nbsp;" + " " + " "
           .replace(/\r\n|\n|\r/g, '<br />');
```

Comment: While your code there looks a lot like you've copied mine and tweaked it, you have dealt with the soft wrapping and HTML escaping issues whereas I haven't, and there's no point in having duplicate answers, so I'll delete mine and upvote yours.

Comment: I added the tab part after your answer because I forgot about it. Now this is pretty common code :-) Upvoted your comment in return.

Comment: It's really not a problem, and the replace stuff is pretty trivial anyway. I've taken cues from other answers plenty of times.

Comment: This feels **much closer** than I thought it would be, but the handling of spaces isn’t actually quite correct. See [this test page](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/105727/web/testing-solution.html). Highlight the spaces, and you can see they aren’t quite right.

Comment: Nice, I tweaked that ever so slightly to avoid lines beginning with `&nbsp;` as much as possible, and it does seem to be working! http://jsfiddle.net/nayyP/3/

Answer (score 11):

Use a [zero-width space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) (`&#8203;`) to preserve whitespace and allow the text to wrap.  The basic idea is to pair each space or sequence of spaces with a zero-width space.  Then replace each space with a non-breaking space.  You'll also want to encode html and add line breaks.

If you don't care about unicode characters, it's trivial.  You can just use `string.replace()`:

```
function textToHTML(text)
{
    return ((text || "") + "")  // make sure it is a string;
        .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
        .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
        .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
        .replace(/\t/g, "    ")
        .replace(/ /g, "&#8203;&nbsp;&#8203;")
        .replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, "<br />");
}
```

If it's ok for the white space to wrap, pair each space with a zero-width space as above.  Otherwise, to keep white space together, pair each *sequence* of spaces with a zero-width space:

```
    .replace(/ /g, "&nbsp;")
    .replace(/((&nbsp;)+)/g, "&#8203;$1&#8203;")
```

To encode unicode characters, it's a little more complex.  You need to iterate the string:

```
var charEncodings = {
    "\t": "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",
    " ": "&nbsp;",
    "&": "&amp;",
    "<": "&lt;",
    ">": "&gt;",
    "\n": "<br />",
    "\r": "<br />"
};
var space = /[\t ]/;
var noWidthSpace = "&#8203;";
function textToHTML(text)
{
    text = (text || "") + "";  // make sure it is a string;
    text = text.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");  // avoid adding two <br /> tags
    var html = "";
    var lastChar = "";
    for (var i in text)
    {
        var char = text[i];
        var charCode = text.charCodeAt(i);
        if (space.test(char) && !space.test(lastChar) && space.test(text[i + 1] || ""))
        {
            html += noWidthSpace;
        }
        html += char in charEncodings ? charEncodings[char] :
        charCode > 127 ? "&#" + charCode + ";" : char;
        lastChar = char;
    }
    return html;
}
```

Now, just a comment.  Without using monospace fonts, you'll lose some formatting.  Consider how these lines of text with a monospace font form columns:

```
ten       seven spaces
eleven    four spaces
```

Without the monospaced font, you will lose the columns:

ten       seven spaces
 eleven    four spaces

It seems that the algorithm to fix that would be very complex.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I’ll try this out soon. Questions: What was your comment about “If you don’t care about Unicode?” (I do, generally, very much so.) The monospace bit is of course true, though the plaintext source I have is actually already assumed to be displayable in variable-width fonts.

Comment: @Alan - In order to escape unicode characters such as `ñ`, you need to use their character codes (ie, `&#241;`).  It isn't feesible to get at the character code from within a call to `replace()`, so the string has to be iterated to deal with the characters one by one.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying. I am not sure those entities are necessary, though. Assuming everything is already in UTF-8, using the header `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` should be enough.

Comment: Does seem to meet all my needs! :) [Test](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/105727/web/testing-plaintext-html-gilly3.html)

Answer (score 2):

While this doesn't quite meet all your requirements — for one thing it doesn't handle tabs, I've used the following gem, which adds a `wordWrap()` method to Javascript `String`s, on a couple of occasions to do something similar to what you're describing — so it might be a good starting point to come up with something that also does the additional things you want.

```
//+ Jonas Raoni Soares Silva
//@ http://jsfromhell.com/string/wordwrap [rev. #2]

// String.wordWrap(maxLength: Integer,
//                 [breakWith: String = "\n"],
//                 [cutType: Integer = 0]): String
//
//   Returns an string with the extra characters/words "broken".
//
//     maxLength  maximum amount of characters per line
//     breakWith  string that will be added whenever one is needed to
//                break the line
//     cutType    0 = words longer than "maxLength" will not be broken
//                1 = words will be broken when needed
//                2 = any word that trespasses the limit will be broken

String.prototype.wordWrap = function(m, b, c){
    var i, j, l, s, r;
    if(m < 1)
        return this;
    for(i = -1, l = (r = this.split("\n")).length; ++i < l; r[i] += s)
        for(s = r[i], r[i] = ""; s.length > m; r[i] += s.slice(0, j) + ((s = s.slice(j)).length ? b : ""))
            j = c == 2 || (j = s.slice(0, m + 1).match(/\S*(\s)?$/))[1] ? m : j.input.length - j[0].length
            || c == 1 && m || j.input.length + (j = s.slice(m).match(/^\S*/)).input.length;
    return r.join("\n");
};
```

I'd also like to comment that it seems to me as though, in general, you'd want to use a monospaced font if tabs are involved because the width of words would vary with the proportional font used (making the results of using of tab stops very font dependent).

**Update**: Here's a slightly more readable version courtesy of an online [javascript beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org):

```
String.prototype.wordWrap = function(m, b, c) {
    var i, j, l, s, r;
    if (m < 1)
        return this;
    for (i = -1, l = (r = this.split("\n")).length; ++i < l; r[i] += s)
        for (s = r[i], r[i] = ""; s.length > m; r[i] += s.slice(0, j) + ((s =
                s.slice(j)).length ? b : ""))
            j = c == 2 || (j = s.slice(0, m + 1).match(/\S*(\s)?$/))[1] ? m :
            j.input.length - j[0].length || c == 1 && m || j.input.length +
            (j = s.slice(m).match(/^\S*/)).input.length;
    return r.join("\n");
};
```

Comment: Kind of tricky to extend a function that is essentially obfuscated

Comment: @Alan H.: Yeah, and hard to debug, too. I think the author intended it to be used in a bookmarklets -- which is where I've used it -- and so tried to minimize it length (rather than to make it hard to understand). Expanding it would be a great way to learn what it does in preparation for enhancements or other modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Is is very simple if you use jQuery library in your project.

Just one line  ,Add `asHTml` extenstion to String Class and :

```
var plain='&lt;a&gt; i am text plain &lt;/a&gt;'
plain.asHtml();
/* '<a> i am text plain </a>' */
```

DEMO :http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/B6vGG/3/

> **Note : You will not have to access to DoM . Just use builder design pattern of jQuery  `$('<tagName />')`**

Comment: I don’t think that solves the problem at hand. You are starting with an HTML string and haven’t tested the case of arbitrary amounts of whitespace in the plain-text source.